# When do I need zlib in OpenSSL?

Tags: configuration, compilation, openssl, zlib

Some site describe config & make for OpenSSL with zlib while I can do it without zlib.

It means zlib is not necessary for openSSL in some case.

Does anyone tell me what case OpenSSL does compression or decompression?

The [answer from @Giacomo1968](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772857/117259) is useful.
I want to know how to choose if I use –z or not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The [answer from @Giacomo1968](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772857/117259) is useful.
> I want to know how to choose if I use –z or not?

That's easy. Compression leaks information in protocols like HTTPS and SPDY, so you should *not* use it. Since you should not use it, there's no reason to configure with it. See Rizzo and Duong's CRIME attack.

There's another option to `configure` you might be interested in: `no-comp`. It disables compression independent of `zlib`.

---

> Does anyone tell me what case OpenSSL does compression or decompression?

By default, compression is enabled unless you disable it at compile time or runtime. If compression *is* available, then you have to disable it at runtime with the `SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION` context options:

```
const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
if(method == NULL) handleFailure();

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if(ctx == NULL) handleFailure();

const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
```

---

For completeness, Firefox does not support compression. Firefox's configure used to be broken out of the box, so the browser was not vulnerable to the compression attacks. See the bug report, [Build NSS with the TLS zlib compression code and add the security.ssl.enable_compression preference to enable it](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580679).

Answer (score 6):

The answer is right [in the manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-enc.html). It relates to the `-z` option:

> “Compress or decompress clear text using zlib before encryption or after decryption. This option exists only if OpenSSL with compiled with zlib or zlib-dynamic option.”

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add some information on "`zlib` ssl compression, CRIME attack, BREACH attack", that I found not clear enough when read the answers.

#### A quick summary:

- TLS used `zlib` for compression, that is vulnerable to CRIME attack. To fix that, it requires either clients(browsers) or servers to refuse compression in TLS. Apache httpd and nginx changed tls compression to false as default. Browser vendors(Firefox did) disable tls compression. So disabling compression (build without `zlib`), everything still works.
- CRIME attack doesn't only affect TLS protocols. HTTP also uses compression so it's also affected. BREACH is a variant attack of CRIME targeting HTTP. But it can be mitigated via CSRF tokens.

Good references and check:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/CRIME
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580679
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53219#c10
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/BREACH_(security_exploit)